# Alternative to VBA GoalSeek

Tags: excel, vba

Does there exist an alternative to GoalSeek in VBA? My worksheet is filled with functions that do not like GoalSeek called from subroutines, and I'm looking for a alternative for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

How about Excel Solver? It can be automated too and allows for significantly more complicated inputs

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/using-the-solver-vba-functions